# Segmentation fault using pthreads and sscanf in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I am getting a segmentation fault due to the first `sscanf` statement in the transaction method. I am unsure why this is occurring. I have tried to change the `sscanf` statement and variables but that did not help. I do not have much experience with debugging but the code stops and turns bright red after the first `sscanf` statement in the transaction method is performed and the rest of the code will not run in the debugger. When I try to run the code without the debugger in visual studio code it runs, granted the output is incorrect as the content of the assignment_5_input.txt is:

```
A1 balance 5000
A2 balance 5000
A3 balance 5000
A4 balance 5000
A5 balance 5000
C1 deposit A2 1000
C2 withdraw A1 300 deposit A4 200
C3 deposit A3 500 withdraw A4 400 withdraw A1 100
C4 withdraw A1 40000 withdraw A2 800
C5 withdraw A5 5000
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define max_lines 100
#define max_len 1000

struct ThreadArgs {
    char *data;
    int *account;
};

//mutex to control thread execution
pthread_mutex_t lock;

void *transaction(void *arg){

  struct ThreadArgs *args = (struct ThreadArgs *)arg;
  char *data_array = args->data;
  int *account_array = args->account;

  int deposit = 0;
  int withdraw = 0;
  int acc_num = 0;

  char wordd[] = "deposit";

  char wordw[] = "withdraw";

  char ddata[strlen(data_array) + 1]; 
    strcpy(ddata, data_array);

  printf("%s", ddata);

  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);  // ENTRY

 if (strstr(ddata, wordd) != NULL) {
   
    sscanf(ddata, "deposit A%d %d", &acc_num, &deposit);

    account_array[acc_num - 1] += deposit;

    printf("Deposit: %d\n", deposit);
    printf("Account Number: %d\n", acc_num);


}

if (strstr(ddata, wordw) != NULL) {
   
  //sscanf(ddata, "withdraw A%d %d", &acc_num, &withdraw);

  if (account_array[acc_num - 1] - withdraw >= 0) {

      account_array[acc_num - 1] -= withdraw;

      printf("Withdrawal: %d\n", withdraw);

      printf("Account Number: %d\n", acc_num);
      
    }

}
  free(args);
  
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); // EXIT
  
  return NULL;
    
}

int main() {

  //variables
  int line = 0;

  char data[max_lines][max_len];

  int num_account = 0;

  int num_client = 0;

  int num_account_count = 0;

  int num_client_count = 0;

  //opening file
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("assignment_5_input.txt", "r");

  if (fp == NULL){

    printf("File could not open.\n");
    return 1;

  }

  while (!feof(fp) && !ferror(fp)){

    if (fgets(data[line], max_len, fp) != NULL){

      line++;

    }

  }

  fclose(fp);

  for (int i = 0; i < line; i++){

    if (sscanf(data[i], "A%d balance ", &num_account)){  

    num_account_count++; 
    }

    if (sscanf(data[i], "C%d ", &num_client)){

      num_client_count++;
    }

 }

  //account info

  int account[num_account_count];

  //putting balance in for each account
  for (int i = 0; i < num_account_count; i++) {
      int balance = 0;
      sscanf(data[i], "A%d balance %d\n", &num_account, &balance);
      account[num_account - 1] = balance;
  }

  //client info

  pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL); 

  pthread_t threads[num_client_count];

  for (int i = num_account_count; i < line; i++) {

    struct ThreadArgs *args = malloc(sizeof(struct ThreadArgs));
    args->data = data[i];
    args->account = account;

    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, transaction, (void *)args);
    }

  for (int i = 0; i < num_client; i++){

    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

   }

  pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

  printf("No. of Accounts: %d\n", num_account);
  printf("No. of Clients: %d\n", num_client);

  for (int i = 0; i < num_account_count; i++) {
      printf("A%d balance: %d\n", i+1, account[i]);
  }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With code like `if (sscanf(data[i], "A%d balance ", &num_account))`, better as `if (sscanf(data[i], "A%d balance ", &num_account) == 1)`.

Comment: Your scanf line will always return 0 because they try to match the string from the beginning. The strings start with C1 for example but you try to match "withdraw A2"  This will always fail. If statements around the scanf will show this issue.

Comment: And one helpful advice for debugging multiple threads: first get your code running in a single thread. When you don't see any issues switch to multiple threads.

Comment: Your code will also not take care of multiple withdrawals or multiple deposits in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Your `pthread_join` loop has the wrong index limits. Try this instead:

```
...
for (int i = num_account_count; i < line; i++){
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}
...
```

Comment: This is correct. But it doesn't solve the OPs issue.

Comment: @hko For me it worked. It ran without a segmentation fault. There may be other issues, but that wasn't what OP asked for.

Comment: OP asked to fix a segmentation fault. There can still be a segmentation fault due to this line `account_array[acc_num - 1] += deposit;`  and this line `if (account_array[acc_num - 1] - withdraw >= 0)` because sscanf  return value is not checked and acc_num can be 0. Meaning you access `account_array[-1]`

Comment: There are a number of issues with the program, I get it, but I think argument sanitizing is a separate topic.

Comment: Don't think it is a separate topic. Accessing `account_array[-1]` is causing a segfault. And in the current code `accont_array[-1]` is executed. 
Maybe it is machine dependent. On my machine the incorrect pthread_join doesn't cause a segfault. It is the lines I posted. But I guess we will never know which one the OP faced unless he will get back to this thread.